# while connect https it shows an undefined error

Tags: node.js, express

I have included the pem, key and password inside the opttions.

```
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443,function(error)
{
  console.log(error)
});
```

This connection gives an "undefined". How to know the error details or what could be the reason of error

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return any error. Read [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serverlisten)

To catch an error use an error event like so:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = https.createServer(..);

server.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

server.listen(8000);
```